# How to template big postgresql query with a temporary table in python?

Tags: python, postgresql

Let's say I have an extremely complicated and long postgres file (`daily_pipeline.sql`) that performs many inserts, updates, statistics calculations, etc...

The input to this file would be a table of new data that is received every day via a data dump.

The strategy I see as working the best would be to have a templated SQL file like so:

```
create temp table todays_data as (
  %s
);

-- do all my inserts

-- do all my updates

-- do all my calculations
```

Then in python I'd read in the new dataset with something like `pandas`, and format my new dataset into this templated file into the `todays_data` temporary table, write the now-formatted file to a new file `daily_pipeline_formatted.sql`, and execute that file from the command line using `psql -f daily_pipeline_formatted.sql`.

I've looked into templating using something like `jinja` but I couldn't find much about templating an entire temporary table.

Does anybody have any direction on how to do this/what resources I can use?

Comment: Why? If you are in Python just do all the work there instead of passing back and forth to a file and then using `psql`. As to dynamic sql(table creation) see [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) from `psycopg2`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver reason is because I'm executing this from airflow which is running out of memory when I attempt this all from python using `psycopg2`s `.execute` method with a formatted string. After some [digging](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134887/open-execute-huge-sql-file) I found this strategy as the "preferred method" for very large queries (my temporary table has millions of rows and the query is very long).

Comment: If you are moving this amount of data you should be using `COPY`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver any chance you'd be willing to demonstrate how to use `copy` to dynamically add data to a temporary table, and then simply select the data from that temporary table? That would be the simplest case for me. I'm struggling to understand how to use this command :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough draft:

```
import psycopg2                                                                                                                                                            
from psycopg2 import sql
from datetime import date    

cat csv_test.csv 
1, 1
3, 4

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
                                                                          
cur = con.cursor()                                                                       

tbl_name = date.today().isoformat() + "-" + "tmp_table"

tbl_sql = sql.SQL("CREATE TEMP TABLE {} (id integer, fld_1 integer)").format(sql.Identifier(tbl_name)) 

cur.execute(tbl_sql)

cp_sql = sql.SQL("COPY {} FROM STDIN WITH CSV").format(sql.Identifier(tbl_name))

with open("/home/aklaver/csv_test.csv") as csv_file:
    cur.copy_expert(cp_sql, csv_file)

cur.execute(sql.SQL("select * from {}").format(sql.Identifier(tbl_name)))

cur.fetchall()
[(1, 1), (3, 4)]
```